# How to prevent line break in citation with an argument?

Tags: line-breaking, citing

If I cite a bibliography item with an additional argument, for example `\cite[p.~6]{bib_item}`, it can happen that there is a line break before the automatically inserted argument, such as:

> text text text [4,
>
> p. 6]

or

> text text text [5, pp. 11-
>
> 13]

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: A workaround would be to wrap the `\cite` command in an `\mbox`.

Comment: @Andrey I was just going to mention it, but my experiments show that the command `\sloppy` is often necessary as it tends to exceed the margin.

Comment: @Harrold: It's natural that you get overrun lines when you use longer boxes often. But instead of `\sloppy` I would advise changing the text (adding, deleting or swapping a word or two) so that TeX does not issue warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not using any packages redefining `\cite` & friends, here's a solution. (Andrey Vihrov's comments about `\mbox`es and `\sloppy` still apply.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\makeatletter
% \def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}% OLD
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa ,~#2\fi}]}% NEW
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text that is just long enough to create an unwanted line break \cite[p.~99]{test}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{test} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Replaced `\penalty\@m\` with `~` in the definition of `\@cite`.