# Bad line break in an epigraph-like definition with a citation

Tags: line-breaking, citing, epigraphs

In a book project, I am using the `epigraph` [epigraph doc](ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph/epigraph.pdf) package for important quotations that should be nicely set off from the text and also include the source citation.  That all works nicely.

I tried to define something similar to give a similar quotation for a section or subsection, calling it an "epigram".  The two arguments are the text of the quotation and the source.

```
\newcommand*{\epigram}[2]{%
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
    \normalfont\emph{#1}\hfill---#2\par\vspace{1ex}}
    }
```

I find this works fine, if the source is a plain `\cite` (or other `natbib` forms, e.g.,

```
\epigram{The dominant principle which characterizes my graphic tables and my figurative maps is to make
    immediately appreciable to the eye, as much as possible, the proportions of numeric results. ...
    Not only do my maps speak, but even more, they count, they calculate by the eye.}{\cite{Minard:1862:book}}
```

which renders nicely as

[image]

However, if my `cite` includes a page reference, as in

```
\epigram{At the time, the effect of lithography in the field of duplication was as great as has been the introduction in our time 
of rapid-copying techniques such as Xerox}{\citep[p. 57]{Robinson:1982}}
```

I get an unwanted line break before the page number,

[image]

Is there someway I can modify the definition of `\epigram` to avoid this?
It is also not clear why, in the first example, the quote is printed without indentation, but in the 2nd it is indented.

**EDIT:**
Here is a minimal example, but for some reason it doesn't work -- the inline .bib items do not resolve, and the two `epigram`s give the same result, not illustrating the problem I have in my book project. I'm stumped.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{epigraph}         %% section quotations
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.8\textwidth}

% define a short version of an epigraph
\newcommand*{\epigram}[2]{%
    {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
    \normalfont\emph{#1}\hfill---#2\par\vspace{1ex}}
    }

\usepackage[comma]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Minard:1862:book,
  title = {Des Tableaux Graphiques et des Cartes Figuratives},
  publisher = {E. Thunot et Cie},
  year = {1862},
  author = {C. J. Minard},
  address = {Paris},
  note = {{\Loc{ENPC: 3386/C161, BNF: Tolbiac, V-16168}; 8 p. and plate(s)}},
  comment = {ENPC no. 36658 (cot 3386) lists this as 1861, n.p.},
  keywords = {tableaux-graphique},
  url = {http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/minard-maps}
}
@BOOK{Robinson:1982,
  title = {Early Thematic Mapping in the History of Cartography},
  publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
  year = {1982},
  author = {Arthur H. Robinson},
  address = {Chicago},
  isbn = {0-226-72285-6},
  lccn = {GA201 .R63 1982}
}

}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}

An opening epigraph:

\epigraph{There is, in nature, perhaps nothing older than motion, concerning
which the books written by philosophers are neither few nor small; nevertheless
I have discovered by experiment some properties of it which are worth knowing
and which have not hitherto been either observed or demonstrate}{Galileo,
Dialogues and Mathematical Demonstrations Concerning Two New Sciences (1638)}



\section{First test}
A section epigram that works:

\epigram{The dominant principle which characterizes my graphic tables and my
figurative maps is to make immediately appreciable to the eye, as much as
possible, the proportions of numeric results. ... Not only do my maps speak, but
even more, they count, they calculate by the eye.}{\cite{Minard:1862:book}}


\section{Second test}
One that doesn't:

\epigram{At the time, the effect of lithography in the field of duplication was
as great as has been the introduction in our time of rapid-copying techniques
such as Xerox}{\citep[p. 57]{Robinson:1982}}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT2:**
Ah, this problem [is discussed in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18132/how-to-prevent-line-break-in-citation-with-an-argument?rq=1%20is%20discussed%20in%20this%20question). Using `\mbox{}` around the `\cite{}` solves the problem

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Put your code into a minimal compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: OK, will do tomorrow @work, but I thought this might be simple enough for someone to spot the source of the problem.